# SP2-0042: unknown command "ENDD" - rest of line ignored

Tags: bash, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have script which is calling sqlplus to perform an operation. But, the sqlplus is returning this error always once the script is executed.

unknown command "ENDD" - rest of line ignored.

Here is my sql written inside the script :

```
map=sqlplus -s <<ENDD
$db_connection_string
   SET BLANKLINES ON
   SET VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF FEEDBACK OFF
   ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=$MY_DB;
   select
      TRIM(( select Col1 from tableA where tableB.col2=col2 and  col3 = 100)) ||'#' ||
      TRIM(tableB.col3 )||'#'||
      tableB.col4 ||'#'||
      tableB.col5 ||'#'||
      tableB.col6 ||'#'||
      TRIM(( select tableC.col1 from tableC  WHERE tableC.col2=10050 AND tableC.col4 = 1 and tableC.col3 = tableB.col4)) AS ACT#TNID#INS#DC#CHNL#EXTSYSIDK
   from tableB
   where
      tableB.col3='$evn'
   and rownum <2;
ENDD
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) syntax:

```
map=$(sqlplus -s <<ENDD
...
ENDD
)
```

Comment: hi, I have used back ticks -

Comment: I'd recommend using `$( ... )` instead of backticks: they are much more visible and are easy to nest.